# React rails app not executing onClick handler when props are used in a conditional expression

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I've been having an issue all day that has been driving me nuts. My project is basically building a chatbot with the React Rails gem, with a top level Alt Container, main component and a child component.

I'm having issues getting the `onClick` handlers in the child component to fire under specific circumstances.

## The problem

I can not get the `onClick` function of the `ExampleChildComponent` component to fire when running in React Rails and if the component is being rendered inside a conditional statement which uses an Alt js store.

The app works perfectly fine when hosted with Webpack, but using the React-Rails gem, Babelify, and Browserify I get the above issue.

## Project description

I'm using the following React related technologies:

- Babelify
- React
- React Rails
- Webpack
- Alt

I'm developing side by side with Webpack and Rails. I work in Webpack and then switch over to Rails to make sure everything works. My project works 100% perfectly using Webpack, React hot loader and HTML Webpack Plugin but breaks upon being run by Rails.

I have a top level component which wraps everything into an Alt Container.

```
import React from 'react';
import AltContainer from 'alt/AltContainer';
import ExampleStore from './stores/ExampleStore';
import ExampleActions from './actions/ExampleActions'
import ExampleComponent from './components/ExampleComponent';

export default class ChatContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    ExampleStore.fetchSurvey();
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <AltContainer
        stores={{ExampleStore: ExampleStore}}
        actions={{ExampleActions: ExampleActions}}>
        <ExampleComponent/>
      </AltContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

In my main ExampleComponent I have the following code, which swaps in and out components depending on my Alt store's state:

```
import React from 'react';
import ExampleChildComponent from './ExampleChildComponent';

export default class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    const isReady = this.props.ExampleStore.isReady;
    return <div>{isReady ? <ExampleChildComponent/>: 'Loading...'}</div>;
  }
}
```

An example child component type would be the following FaceMood component:

```
import React from 'react';
export default class ExampleChildComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick () {
    console.log('Example child component clicked');
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div onClick={this.handleClick}>
        Example Child Component
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This all works perfectly fine in Webpack but in React-Rails the `handleClick` function is not being executed when I click on the `<div>` in the ExampleChildComponent.

Interestingly, I managed to narrow the issue down to the following line of code in my `ExampleComponent` component:

```
return <div>{isReady ? <ExampleChildComponent/>: 'Loading...'}</div>;
```

Now if I don't refer to the `this.props.ExampleStore.isReady` at ALL, the onClick event handler works fine:

```
return <div><ExampleChildComponent/></div>
```

This is of course not ideal, as I want my Pane to show different component types depending on the current progress in the chatbot conversation.

I'm pretty much at my wits end so I hope some of you can help me!

## Extra information

The prop `this.props.ExampleStore.isReady` is set using [Alt.js' async datasource methods](http://alt.js.org/docs/async/). Its a javascript promise that sets the `isReady` flag to true after the data fetching has been completed.

Here is the code for the Flux actions:

```
import alt from '../utils/Alt';

class ExampleActions {
  fetchSurvey() {
    this.dispatch();
  }

  updateSurvey(survey) {
    this.dispatch(survey);
  }

  fetchSurveyFailed(errorMessage) {
    this.dispatch(errorMessage);
  }
}

export default alt.createActions(ExampleActions);
```

Now the code for the Flux store:

```
import alt from '../utils/Alt';
import ExampleActions from '../actions/ExampleActions';
import ExampleSource from '../sources/ExampleSource';

class ExampleStore {
  constructor() {
    this.isReady = false;
    this.bindListeners({
      handleFetchSurvey: ExampleActions.FETCH_SURVEY,
      handleUpdateSurvey: ExampleActions.UPDATE_SURVEY,
      handleFetchingSurveyFailed: ExampleActions.FETCH_SURVEY_FAILED
    });
    this.registerAsync(ExampleSource);
  }

  handleFetchSurvey() {
  }

  handleUpdateSurvey() {
    this.isReady = true;
  }

  handleFetchingSurveyFailed(errorMessage) {
  }
}

export default alt.createStore(ExampleStore, 'ExampleStore');
```

Now the code for the flux datasource:

```
import ExampleActions from '../actions/ExampleActions';

const MockQuestions = [
  {

  }
];

const ExampleSource = () => {
  return {
    fetchSurvey() {
      return {
        remote() {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              if (true) {
                resolve(MockQuestions);
              } else {
                reject('Fetch failed');
              }
            }, 500);
          });
        },

        local() {
          return null;
        },

        loading: ExampleActions.fetchSurvey,
        success: ExampleActions.updateSurvey,
        error: ExampleActions.fetchSurveyFailed
      };
    }
  };
}

export default ExampleSource;
```

The `onClick()` function can be seen in the react dev tools app also, its just not executing it!

[Screenshot](http://puu.sh/jUQwX/323f346928.png)

Comment: It feels weird to pass a store as a prop, try to access the store directly.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I never even considered doing that, we shall see if it works!

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am facing something similar with my app.

Comment: @JaakkoKarhu: I never resolved it. One workaround a colleague did was to use CSS to hide and show the components instead of using logic in React to show it. I ended up switching to Webpack with Rails, and now everything works perfectly!